# CakePHP: How to use (if possible) a class inside both Controller, Model and View?

Tags: cakephp, classloader

Supposing I have a StringerHelper(Component|Helper|Behaviour).php class with a method for random strings.

I might need to use this in controllers, models and views.
How can I load it wherever I need to ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would make it a lib and put it in `app/Lib`. If its simply helper methods, make the methods static.

For 2.x

```
app/Lib/Stringer.php
App::uses('Stringer', 'Lib');
```

For 1.x the naming is a bit different

```
app/lib/stringer.php
App::import('Lib', 'Stringer');
```

Usage:

```
Stringer::myHelperMethod([args]);
```

Comment: Until you answered I found uses and import and I have used ::import to bring my class into a model. It worked. So, I have to understand that this is not a good practice but instead I have to use ::uses ? Thank you!

Comment: Depends on your cake version. App::uses is for 2.x and App::import is 1.x but still supported in 2.x